# At jenkins how to display a message(not a plain text) at input section with the variables that comes for the previous stages or commands

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm creating a pipeline where, in the user input section, I aim to display a message that isn't a plain text but rather derived from the output obtained in earlier steps. Specifically, I intend to showcase the repositories that match the provided ApplicationName (where the application name is used to create repositories).

pipeline I am pasting here and I will attach the screenshot for the same:

Pipeline:

pipeline {
agent any
environment {

```
    creds = credentials("xm_com")
    search_string = "${params.ApplicationName.toLowerCase()}"
}
parameters {
    choice(name: 'CommonName', choices: ['CP', 'Mag', 'COMMON', 'NOW'], description: 'Framework or CommonName')
    string(name: 'ApplicationName', defaultValue: '', description: 'Enter Application Name')
    choice(name: 'CodeOwner', choices: ['Osd', 'TF', 'TM'], description: 'Choose Code Owner')
    text(name: 'Description', defaultValue: '', description: 'Write 1-2 lines about the purpose of repo')
}
stages {
    stage("read parameters") {
        steps {
            script {
                echo "CommonName: ${params.CommonName.toLowerCase()}"
                echo "ApplicationName: ${params.ApplicationName.toLowerCase()}"
                echo "Code_Owner: ${params.CodeOwner}"
                echo "Description: ${params.Description}"
                echo "Tool: $tool"
            }
        }
    }
    stage("Check ApplicationName and Confirm Build") {
        steps {
            script {
                // Pull list of repositories
                sh """
                    curl -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json' -H 'Authorization: token ${creds_PSW}' 'https://api.github.com/orgs/org/repos?visibility=all&page=1&per_page=500' | grep '\"name\":' | sed 's/\"name\": \"\\([^\\\"]*\\)\",/\\1/' > repositories
                """
                
                // Check if any repositories match or repository in the search criteria 
                def matched_repositories = []
                for (repo in readFile('repositories').readLines()) {
                    if (repo.toLowerCase().contains(search_string)) {
                        matched_repositories.add(repo)
                    }
                }
    
                if (matched_repositories.empty) {

                    echo "No repositories matched the search criteria."
                    input message: 'No repositories present with the given name Do you want to proceed with the build?', ok: 'Yes', submitter: 'user'
                } else {
                   // facing problem here need to display matched_repositories
                    def userInput = input message: "Similar repos exist: ${matched_repositories.join(', ')}. Do you want to proceed with creating a new repository?",
                        ok: "Yes",
                        parameters: [
                            booleanParam(defaultValue: false, description: 'Proceed with creating a new repository', name: 'Proceed')
                        ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Solution on how to display a variable at input if possible.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ChHT.png)